# Anaconda, ipython2.7

Tags: python, ipython

I have recently installed Anaconda , which has ipython 2.7. Whenever, i try to get help from help(). and search for modules,it shows the following. After this, the terminal takes in commands but does not execute them.This happens in all the tabs i open in the same kernel, but on opening a new kernel , it works like before, except when you type (help) then modules! Please help

Anaconda\lib\pkgutil.py:110: DeprecationWarning: The compiler package is deprecated and removed in Python 3.x.
  **import**(name)

Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pls.py:7: DeprecationWarning: This module has been moved to cross_decomposition and will be removed in 0.16
  "removed in 0.16", DeprecationWarning)

Comment: The attempt to list modules tries to import every module on your system. This might take a few minutes, and naughty modules which do things on import might break it in all sorts of ways. What happens if you do it in a plain Python shell?

Comment: @ThomasK: Why do you say it tries to import everything? I don't see anything in the post indicating it would do that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2357112: If you do `help()` on your system and then type `modules` (which I think the user is doing), it tries to list and describe all the modules on your system. I remembered, and confirmed by experimenting, that this works by trying to import every available module.

Comment: @ThomasK: Huh. It looks like it does do something like that, though it's not *every* module. I'm not sure which ones are excluded.

Comment: in plain python shell it works just fine! but in ipython2.7 , i get this problem. However, when i try help('specifying a particular module') it works fine.

Comment: First off try updating.  type" conda update conda" and "conda update ipython".  Secondly do you have 2 python versions on the system? And lastly could you put in your post exactly what you are typing and the return values for each?